Does USA offer same day settlement on money market funds?
I am looking to know if USA offers same day settlements. Someone have told me some time ago that one firm offers it on FIGXX , When I look at Fidelity site or morningstar, could not confirm and I some how could not connect with that person. He has also told that the minimum of $1M is not enforced when it is done on subscription basis. I could not find what is subscription in money market funds. If this community can help.

On Fidelity, settlement for money market funds is generally same day. Orders for money markets funds fill once a day, at market close, and will settle same day.

per reddit and bogleheads same day settlement is available.
